# Trouble Writing to Jest Mocked Prisma Database

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, prisma, jest-mock-extended

I have two databases that I need to interact with in my code.  I have a simple function that takes an object and writes it to my PostgreSQL database using Prisma.  I've tested the function with Postman, and it works perfectly, but when I try to execute it using a Jest mock (using the singleton pattern found in the [Prisma unit testing guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing)), it returns undefined indicating that it didn't interact with the database and create the new record.  Here's my code:

##### /prisma/clinical-schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "./generated/clinical"
}

datasource clinicalDatabase {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/clinical-data?schema=public"
}

model pcc_webhook_update {
  id                  Int                       @id @default(autoincrement())
  event_type          String
  organization_id     Int
  facility_id         Int
  patient_id          Int
  resource_id         String?
  webhook_date        DateTime                  @default(now()) @clinicalDatabase.Timestamptz(6)
  status              pcc_webhook_update_status @default(pending)
  status_changed_date DateTime?                 @clinicalDatabase.Timestamptz(6)
  error_count         Int                       @default(0)

  @@unique([organization_id, facility_id, patient_id, resource_id, event_type, status])
}

enum pcc_webhook_update_status {
  pending
  processing
  processed
  error
}
```

##### /prisma/clinical-client.ts

```js
import { PrismaClient } from './generated/clinical';

const prismaClinical = new PrismaClient();

export default prismaClinical;
```

##### /testing/prisma-clinical-mock.ts

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '../prisma/generated/clinical';
import { mockDeep, mockReset, DeepMockProxy } from 'jest-mock-extended';
import prisma from '../prisma/clinical-client';

jest.mock('../prisma/clinical-client', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: mockDeep<PrismaClient>()
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  mockReset(prismaClinicalMock);
});

export const prismaClinicalMock = prisma as unknown as DeepMockProxy<PrismaClient>;
```

Everything up to this point follows the conventions outlined by the Prisma unit testing docs.  The only modification I made was to make it database specific.  Below is my function and tests.  The request object in `handle-pcc-webhooks.ts` is a sample http request object, the body of which contains the webhook data I care about.

##### /functions/handle-pcc-webhooks/handler.ts

```js
import prismaClinical from '../../../prisma/clinical-client';
import { pcc_webhook_update } from '../../../prisma/generated/clinical';
import { requestObject } from './handler.types';

export const handlePccWebhook = async (request: requestObject) => {

  try {

    const webhook = JSON.parse(request.body);

    // if the webhook doesn't include a resource id array, set it to an array with an empty string to ensure processing and avoid violating
    // the multi-column unique constraint on the table
    const { resourceId: resourceIds = [''] } = webhook;

    let records = [];

    for (const resourceId of resourceIds) {

      // update an existing record if one exists in the pending state, otherwise create a new entry
      const record: pcc_webhook_update = await prismaClinical.pcc_webhook_update.upsert({
        where: {
          organization_id_facility_id_patient_id_resource_id_event_type_status: {
            organization_id: webhook.orgId,
            facility_id: webhook.facId,
            patient_id: webhook.patientId,
            resource_id: resourceId,
            event_type: webhook.eventType,
            status: 'pending'
          }
        },
        update: {
          webhook_date: new Date()
        },
        create: {
          event_type: webhook.eventType,
          organization_id: webhook.orgId,
          facility_id: webhook.facId,
          patient_id: webhook.patientId,
          resource_id: resourceId,
          status: 'pending' // not needed
        }
      });

      records.push(record);
    }

    return records;

  } catch (error) {

    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

##### /functions/handle-pcc-webhooks/handler.spec.ts

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import MockDate from 'mockdate';
import { prismaClinicalMock } from '../../../testing/prisma-clinical-mock';
import { createAllergyAddRecord } from './__mocks__/allergy';
import { requestObject } from './handler.types';
import { handlePccWebhook } from './handler';

describe('allergy.add', () => {

  let requestObject: requestObject;
  let allergyAddRecord: any;

  beforeAll(() => {
    requestObject = getRequestObject('allergy.add');
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    MockDate.set(new Date('1/1/2022'));
    allergyAddRecord = createAllergyAddRecord(new Date());
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    MockDate.reset();
  });

  test('should create an allergy.add database entry', async() => {

    prismaClinicalMock.pcc_webhook_update.create.mockResolvedValue(allergyAddRecord);

    // this is where I would expect handlePccWebhook to return the newly created database
    // record, but instead it returns undefined.  If I run the function outside of this
    // unit test, with the same input value, it functions perfectly
    await expect(handlePccWebhook(requestObject)).resolves.toEqual([allergyAddRecord]);
  });
});

// This just builds a request object with the current webhook being tested
function getRequestObject(webhookType: string) {

  // read the contents of request object file as a buffer, then convert it to JSON
  const rawRequestObject = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../sample-data/handle-pcc-webhook-request.json'));
  const requestObject: requestObject = JSON.parse(rawRequestObject.toString());

  // read the contents of the webhook file as a buffer, then convert it to a string
  const rawWebhook = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `../../sample-data/${webhookType}.json`));
  const webhookString = rawWebhook.toString();

  // set the body of the request object to the contents of the target webhook
  requestObject.body = webhookString;

  return requestObject;
}
```

Finally, here is the result of running the unit test:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after banging my had against the wall for a few hours, I figured out the issue.  In my `handler.spec.ts` file, I had the following line:

```js
prismaClinicalMock.pcc_webhook_update.create.mockResolvedValue(allergyAddRecord);
```

what that does is mock the value returned for any `create` functions run using Prisma.  The issue is that my function is using an `upsert` function, which I wasn't explicitly mocking, thus returning undefined.  I changed the above line to

```js
prismaClinicalMock.pcc_webhook_update.upsert.mockResolvedValue(allergyAddRecord);
```

and it started working.